# Delete file in IsolatedStorage on Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage

I want to delete a file, which was generated by my Windows Phone 8. This is my code, but I'm getting an exception: Unable to delete file. But I don't know why. Any ideas?

```
if (myIsoStore.FileExists(fileName))
{
  myIsoStore.DeleteFile(fileName);
}
```

Comment: You still have the file open?

Comment: Depends on how you opened it in the first place - your code excerpt does not cover that part.

Comment: I'm using a StreamWriter: StreamWriter writeFile = new StreamWriter(new IsolatedStorageFileStream(fileName, FileMode.CreateNew, myIsoStore)); And then I'm writing something and call: writeFile.Flush(); writeFile.Close();

Comment: This works for me: `using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()) { using (var f = new StreamWriter( new IsolatedStorageFileStream("foo.bar", FileMode.CreateNew, store))) { f.Flush(); f.Close(); if (store.FileExists("foo.bar")) { store.DeleteFile("foo.bar"); }}}` - so the problem must be elsewhere.

Comment: Well. Your code is working for me, too. I have more information about the error: Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream. First time it will also work with my code, but if I'm run it directly again, I'm getting this error.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36005/discussion-between-jlahd-and-thomas-sebastian-jensen)

Comment: If you are having issues with isolated storage, I created a free DLL called EZ_Iso that does all the heavy lifting for you. Go check it out at my tech blog http://anthonyrussell.info/postpage.php?name=47 I also provide simple instructions there on how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in the Windows Phone 8 emulator, some times the aplication lost the permissions of her files in the isolated storage.

You must delete the application from emulator, and from the visual studio re-implement the app, and try again.